# Need to be able to double click cells on sheet1 to creat a list on sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

So I would like to be able to double click multiples cells on sheet1 to creat a list of sorts on sheet2.

The problem with the code I have now is that it just replaces content in one cell on sheet2 instead of seeing it already has content then transferring content to the next cell below it.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:P")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 then
        Cancel = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S13") = Target.Value
    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

So for example I need to be able to double click on E12 sheet1 it fills S13 on sheet2 with  its content. Then I double click on E15 on sheet1 and it sees that S13 on sheet2 has content already so it fills S14 on sheet2 with its content.

Comment: Please provide the code that you are working with.

Comment: Please take the time to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55657725/edit) to clarify it

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S1040000").End(XlUp).offset(1) = Target.Value`